# Iterating though items of Model in MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model

I would like to iterate though the item returned from the `foreach(var item in Model)`. Like `for(int i=0; i <item.length; i++)` and then subsequently write the individual html code for the items returned by the model.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to be able to access `item.length` as the property doesn't exists. Would anyone know how I could iterate through each model item so that I could save up on writing a lot of unnecessary HTML?

So some more context in lieu of the question being unclear:

Let's say my model is

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now I use a DB call to access the model data and parse it to the view via

```
RegisterViewModel model= db.RegisterViewModel.Where(data => data.Name == User.Name);
```

Now I pass this model to the view via `view(model)`

Now to display data for all the students, I can use a

```
model IEnumerable<Project.Models.RegisterViewModel>

@foreach(item in Model) {
    @for(int i=0; i<item.Length;i++) { \\this is where I would like to iterate though the item
    if(item[i]!= null) // using a for loop would avoid me having to write this if condition multiple times.
         <div>@item[i].value</div>
    }
```

}

Comment: What is `item`? Can you show the code for `Model`?

Comment: I am sure I could definitely use a little explanation with the downvote. I believe the question is quite valid as there is littereally nothing I could find on server side to iterate though the elements. The only way I figure is parse the object to the client and use JavaScript for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot iterate over `item` because `item` is of type `RegisterViewModel`. It doesn't make sense to be doing this.

If you want to display the value you could directly use it like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.RegisterViewModel>

@foreach(item in Model) {
    <div>@item.Value</div>
}
```

Also bear in mind that the following line of code in your controller is wrong:

```
RegisterViewModel model = db.RegisterViewModel.Where(data => data.Name == User.Name);
```

The .Where extension method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` so you'd rather have:

```
IEnumerable<RegisterViewModel> model = db.RegisterViewModel.Where(data => data.Name == User.Name);
return View(model);
```

or if you prefer:

```
var model = db.RegisterViewModel.Where(data => data.Name == User.Name);
return View(model);
```

Comment: So is it possible to typecast the item as an ICollection?

Comment: Now that you have updated your question and provided more details it is clear. You cannot iterate over `item` because `item` is not a collection. Basically you already have a collection of the model. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yep thanks, that's what my research led me to find. I was hoping to avoid writing a ton of redundant HTML code if I could just iterate the `item`

Comment: Updated my question with why I wanted to use a for loop to iterate though the item.